# How to use IS NOT NULL in Knex JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, knex.js

I am trying to create the following query using knex:

`SELECT * FROM users group by users.location having users.photo is not null`

as follows:

`knex("users").groupBy("users.location").having("users.photo", "IS NOT", "Null")`

I am getting the following error on this:

`The operator IS NOT is not permitted`

I've gone through their documentation and couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-having), **.havingRaw** is what you need:

```
knex("users").groupBy("users.location").havingRaw("users.photo IS NOT ?", [null]);
```

On the other hand, do a knex.raw at once unless there is any remaining advantage using the builder on this specific case.

Answer (score 40):

Have you tried:

`knex("users").whereNotNull("photo").groupBy("location")`

Comment: I haven't tried but shouldn't having clause be used here?

Comment: @aitchkhan you can chain the commands. 

For example this:
 `knex('table').where({"something":"else"}).whereNull("one_column").whereNotNull("some_column")` 
would create query 
`select * from "table" where "something" = 'else' and "one_column" is null and "some_column" is not null`. 
You can play around with the API here: http://michaelavila.com/knex-querylab/

Comment: Okay, I was not expecting this. Intresting

Answer (score 8):

The docs have the answers. There is `whereNull`, `whereNotNull`, `havingNull`, `havingNotNull` and so on.

From the [DOCS](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-havings):

> **havingNull** — .havingNull(column)
>   Adds a havingNull clause to the query.

```
knex.select('*').from('users').havingNull('email')
```

Outputs:

```
select * from `users` having `email` is null
```

> **havingNotNull** — .havingNotNull(column)
>   Adds a havingNotNull clause to the query.

```
knex.select('*').from('users').havingNotNull('email')
```

Outputs:

```
select * from `users` having `email` is not null
```

Give it a try using the knex query lab: http://michaelavila.com/knex-querylab/